# collectds network plugin is only sending data every 100 seconds

Tags: collectd

I've been banging my head against a wall with this for the last couple of hours, so I have resorted to ask you guys here.

I've got one collectd instance that is set up to take statsd metrics and use the `network` plugin to route them onwards to a main collectd instance that then ships them on to influxdb via the `write_graphite` plugin.

Sending metrics to the `statsd` plugin works (I've checked with `tcpdump` and used the `csv` plugin as a debug tool).

It becomes a problem when it comes to the `network` plugin to ship the collected metrics off to the "main" collectd instance. The `network` plugin seems to only send data once every 100 seconds or when it restarts (I guess it flushes the buffers when it stops).

Here are the configs of the client machine:

/etc/collectd/collectd.conf

```
Hostname "collectd.client"
FQDNLookup false
BaseDir "/var/lib/collectd"
PluginDir "/usr/lib/collectd"
TypesDB "/usr/share/collectd/types.db"
AutoLoadPlugin false
Interval 10

LoadPlugin logfile

<Plugin logfile>
   LogLevel "info"
   File "/var/log/collectd.log"
   Timestamp true
   PrintSeverity true
</Plugin>

<Include "/etc/collectd/conf.d">
    Filter "*.conf"
</Include>
```

/etc/collectd/conf.d/network.conf

```
LoadPlugin network

<Plugin "network">
        <Server "main-instance-ip" "25826">
            SecurityLevel "Encrypt"
            Username "collectd"
            Password "xxxxxxxx"
    </Server>
</Plugin>
```

/etc/collectd/conf.d/collectd.statsd.conf

```
LoadPlugin statsd

<Plugin statsd>
    Host "0.0.0.0"
    Port "8125"
</Plugin>
```

Here's the output of `tcpdump` running for a bit:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -i any udp port 25826
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 65535 bytes
04:49:52.889504 IP ip-10-xxx-xx7-60.ec2.internal.43536 > ip-10-xxx-xx-7.ec2.internal.25826: UDP, length 1337
04:51:52.889498 IP ip-10-xxx-xx7-60.ec2.internal.43536 > ip-10-xxx-xx-7.ec2.internal.25826: UDP, length 1373
04:53:52.889469 IP ip-10-xxx-xx7-60.ec2.internal.43536 > ip-10-xxx-xx-7.ec2.internal.25826: UDP, length 1363
04:55:42.889507 IP ip-10-xxx-xx7-60.ec2.internal.43536 > ip-10-xxx-xx-7.ec2.internal.25826: UDP, length 1375
04:57:42.889504 IP ip-10-xxx-xx7-60.ec2.internal.43536 > ip-10-xxx-xx-7.ec2.internal.25826: UDP, length 1368
04:59:52.889519 IP ip-10-xxx-xx7-60.ec2.internal.43536 > ip-10-xxx-xx-7.ec2.internal.25826: UDP, length 1366
05:01:52.889511 IP ip-10-xxx-xx7-60.ec2.internal.43536 > ip-10-xxx-xx-7.ec2.internal.25826: UDP, length 1363
05:03:42.889507 IP ip-10-xxx-xx7-60.ec2.internal.43536 > ip-10-xxx-xx-7.ec2.internal.25826: UDP, length 1375
05:05:42.889485 IP ip-10-xxx-xx7-60.ec2.internal.43536 > ip-10-xxx-xx-7.ec2.internal.25826: UDP, length 1363
05:07:32.889497 IP ip-10-xxx-xx7-60.ec2.internal.43536 > ip-10-xxx-xx-7.ec2.internal.25826: UDP, length 1375
05:09:32.889477 IP ip-10-xxx-xx7-60.ec2.internal.43536 > ip-10-xxx-xx-7.ec2.internal.25826: UDP, length 1363
05:11:22.889528 IP ip-10-xxx-xx7-60.ec2.internal.43536 > ip-10-xxx-xx-7.ec2.internal.25826: UDP, length 1375
05:13:32.889503 IP ip-10-xxx-xx7-60.ec2.internal.43536 > ip-10-xxx-xx-7.ec2.internal.25826: UDP, length 1395
05:15:42.889484 IP ip-10-xxx-xx7-60.ec2.internal.43536 > ip-10-xxx-xx-7.ec2.internal.25826: UDP, length 1366
05:17:42.889493 IP ip-10-xxx-xx7-60.ec2.internal.43536 > ip-10-xxx-xx-7.ec2.internal.25826: UDP, length 1373
05:19:42.889552 IP ip-10-xxx-xx7-60.ec2.internal.43536 > ip-10-xxx-xx-7.ec2.internal.25826: UDP, length 1368
05:21:52.889502 IP ip-10-xxx-xx7-60.ec2.internal.43536 > ip-10-xxx-xx-7.ec2.internal.25826: UDP, length 1361
05:23:42.889500 IP ip-10-xxx-xx7-60.ec2.internal.43536 > ip-10-xxx-xx-7.ec2.internal.25826: UDP, length 1375
05:25:42.889491 IP ip-10-xxx-xx7-60.ec2.internal.43536 > ip-10-xxx-xx-7.ec2.internal.25826: UDP, length 1363
```

It seems from the output that it has decided to run every ~2 minutes now instead.

Comment: Verify with `tcpdump -i any udp port 25826`, perhaps share an edited version highlighting the gaps in the timestamps.

Comment: @fuero I added the output from `tcpdump`, let me know if you need more

Answer (score 1):

How many values do you collect?

As far as I know, the `network` plugin sends data when its buffer is full. Try to use `MaxPacketSize 1024` directive, or collect more data.